# Calling multiple functions from a ractive on-click

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Is it possible to fire two ractive functions with an on-click event. I assumed it would try to behave the same way the onclick does by using semi colons but it doesn't fire either function.

Template:

```
<div on-click="hello; world;"></div>
```

JS:

```
Ractive.on('hello', function(){
    console.log('hello');
});

Ractive.on('world', function(){
    console.log('world');
});
```

I've tried comma separated and space separated. What would be the correct way to get both of these functions to fire from one on-click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a contrived example similar to @Juan's below, but you could have a custom event that fires the other two.

*Template*

```
<div on-click="custom"></div>
```

*JS*

```
Ractive.on('custom', function() {
  Ractive.fire('hello');
  Ractive.fire('world');
});

Ractive.on('hello', function(){
  console.log('hello');
});

Ractive.on('world', function(){
  console.log('world');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Brett's answer is a good one - for most situations, I'd recommend that. If you wanted to do this in many situations, you could abstract it out like so:

```js
Ractive.prototype.fireEvents = function () {
  var len = arguments.length;
  for ( var i = 0; i < len; i += 1 ) {
    this.fire( arguments[i], this.event );
  }
};

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template'
});

ractive.on({
  foo: function () {
    alert( 'fired foo' );
  },
  bar: function () {
    alert( 'fired bar' );
  },
  baz: function () {
    alert( 'fired baz' );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js'></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' type='text/html'>
  <button on-click='fireEvents("foo","bar","baz")'>fire events</button>
</script>
```

Modifying the prototype like this to add extra functionality you need is totally encouraged.

Comment: _Modifying the prototype like this to add extra functionality you need is totally encouraged._ I am feeling like Ractive project needs a space to list all of these useful mixins so people can be aware of them and use them when necessity arises.

Answer (score 1):

You can fire only one proxy event:

http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/proxy-events

But maybe you can do:

```
<div on-click="hello" ></div>
<div on-click="world" ></div>
<div on-click="helloWorld" ></div>
```

---

```
function hello(){
    console.log('hello');
}

function world(){
    console.log('world');

}
Ractive.on('hello', function(){
    hello();
});

Ractive.on('world', function(){
   world();
});

Ractive.on('helloWorld', function(){

  hello(); world();
});
```